# How do I pre select a marker on react-native-maps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

I trying to display a preselected marker in a react-native app. I am using react-native-maps for displaying maps. Selecting/tapping a marker in a map shows a small toolbar on the bottom that has driving directions button.
[image: Toolbar showing]
When I am displaying a map that only has 1 marker, I want it to be preselected and that tool bar to show but so far I have found no option to do this. The maps shows without toolbar and the toolbar only appear once the marker is tapped.
[image: Toolbar not showing]
This is my code. Notice the preselected option. According to documentation it is only for iOS and I am at the moment trying  it on Android. So understandable that it doesn't work. I have it there just for iOS. I will try to get my hands on an iphone sometime and test there but I am looking for a solution that can work on both Android and iOS.

```
<MapView
   style={{ flex: 1 }}
   initialRegion={{
     latitude: item.lat,
     longitude: item.lon,
     latitudeDelta: 0.0411,
     longitudeDelta: 0.0211,
   }}
   scrollEnabled={false}
   zoomEnabled={false}
>
   <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: item.lat, longitude: item.lon }} isPreselected={true} />
</MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a ref to the Marker via useRef and then when the map renders use ref.showCallout() to always show the callout on a render.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

export default props => {
  const markerRef = useRef(null);

  const onRegionChangeComplete = () => {
    if (markerRef && markerRef.current && markerRef.current.showCallout) {
      markerRef.current.showCallout();
    }
  };

  return (
      <MapView onRegionChangeComplete={onRegionChangeComplete}>
        <MapView.Marker ref={this.markerRef}/>
      </MapView>
  );
};
```

Please see here: [link](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1041)